# How to send message to all players on server? (Server-side)

Tags: minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-forge

How would I send a message to all of the players on the server? (When trying to do so, it only outputs to the console, and I believe that is because the mod is not installed on the client side.)

I have been trying to make a mod for a 1.7.10 server (To put in a 1.7.10 mod pack) that can message all of the players online. I have looked this question up, and have not found any answers.

```
@SideOnly(Side.SERVER)
@SubscribeEvent
public void onDeath(PlayerEvent.Clone event)
{
    if (event.wasDeath) {
        final String[] messages = {"Oh boiss we got a respawner O_O", "How dare ye respawn on me?", "GAAH! You died again!", "._. Just why...", "Was taht me or waas that you? -.-","Why isn't this in hardcore mode? It should be..."};
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(messages.length);
        ChatComponentText text = new ChatComponentText(messages[index]);
        ChatStyle style = new ChatStyle();
        style.setColor(EnumChatFormatting.LIGHT_PURPLE);
        text.setChatStyle(style);
         FMLCommonHandler.instance().getMinecraftServerInstance().getConfigurationManager().sendChatMsg(text);
    System.out.println("Respawned");
    }
}
```

I expect that the server will send a message to all, but only outputs to the console.

Answer (score 1):

A really quick way this could be handled is to create an EventHandler for when a player joins. Then add them to an ArrayList. Then when they leave (Check for kick / quit event). Remove them from the ArrayList. By having an arraylist you can run through this and message every player.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'System.out.println("Respawned");` line will only print to the console.

I believe what you are looking to do is the following:

1) Loop through all the players on the server.
2) Send each player the calculated message.

I'm not 100% sure how to access the player-list off the top of my head, but you need to access the `FMLServerHandler` and get the player-list, OR (the better way) access the `EntityPlayer` objects connected to the player's current world and do the above steps. The second method would only work for the current world, so if you wanted to access all the connections to the server, the first method is the way to go.